# distinct cyclic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $ (G, *) $ be a group.

Say, $\langle a\rangle, \ \langle b\rangle$ are two cyclic subgroups of $G$ of equal orders.

Say $ \ o(a) = o(b) = n  \in \mathbb N , \ n > 1 $

CASE I: $\{ a^p : p \in\mathbb N, \ \gcd(p,n) = 1\} \cap \{ b^p : p \in\mathbb N, \ \gcd(p,n) = 1\} = \phi$

CASE II: $\ \langle a\rangle \not\subset \langle b\rangle \text{ and }\langle b\rangle \not\subset \langle a\rangle$

In both cases I have an intution that $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle \ = \ \{e\}$

Anyone, if you can please prove or counter it.

Comment: Consider the quaternion group.

Comment: If $\langle a \rangle \not = \langle b \rangle$ have prime order, then $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle=\{e\}$. Furthermore if elements $a,b$ of the same order $n$ exist with $a \not \in \langle b \rangle$, then the elements in $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$ have order strictly smaller then $n$.